# i want to add fonts in flutter app, but there is a problem in pubspec.yaml

Tags: android, flutter

This is my pubspec.yaml
Working dir: C:\Users\kom.13\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app1
C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat get
Error on line 22, column 2 of pubspec.yaml: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
â•·
22 â”‚  fonts:
â”‚  ^
â•µ
Process finished with exit code 65

```
name: flutter_app1
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

 fonts:
  - family: Pacifico
  fonts:
  - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf
```

Answer (score 2):

so, you have an indentation issue in the fonts sections. Do this instead:

```
name: flutter_app1
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to:
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true

 fonts:
   - family: Pacifico
     fonts:
       - asset: fonts/Pacifico-Regular.ttf
```

For reference, check this page: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: That's right, need to be precise when making changes to pubspec.yaml or else you will be seeing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think You have an Error of indentation of which means your fonts are not at the correct position, see mine below code.

```
fonts:
    - family: GraphikWide
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Graphik-Wide-Regular.otf
        - asset: fonts/Graphik-Wide-Medium.otf
          weight: 400
    - family: Gibson
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/gibson-regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/gibson-semibold.ttf
          weight: 400
        - asset: fonts/gibson-light.ttf
          weight: 100
```

just replace your full font code in pubspec with my code then do the changes